# How to design/configure a database to support multiple character sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding, multilingual, collation

It's in the beginning stages at this point. Currently, I have a `SQL Server` database that uses a `collation` of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. As I understand it, there is a requirement in the works where multiple languages will need to be supported, specifically languages like Spanish, French, Portuguese, maybe Italian. Dutch and German are possible. Eastern Asian languages like Chinese and Japanese are also likely.

The database platform will either be SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2012, or SQL Server 2014.

This seems like a big undertaking and I'm not sure where or how to start. How do I design a database to support `multiple character sets`?

Example:

- Database Name: Foobar
- Tables in Foobar: dbo.Foo, dbo.Bar

Can dbo.Foo support all these languages listed aove, or must I have a different schema for each `collation`? (I.e. Eng.Foo, Jp.Foo, Fr.Foo) If it's the latter, that means I'll have multiple tables with identical column names but different data.

Any advice on where to start with this task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UTF-16 collation from the beginning. [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) was designed specifically for this purpose.

For more detailed information, I recommend [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/qingsongyao/archive/2009/02/01/utf-16-encoding-and-sql-server-1.aspx) ([second half](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/qingsongyao/archive/2009/02/02/utf-16-encoding-and-sql-server-2.aspx)) and [this page from the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for these resources. However, I don't see any of the resources explicitly saying UTF-16 supports Asian languages.

Comment: It is implicitly implied in the sentence from wikipedia `UTF-16 (16-bit Unicode Transformation Format) is a character encoding capable of encoding all 1,112,064 possible characters in Unicode.`. I know that CJK (that is the keyword that you should google on, it stands for Chinese Japanese Korean) support works as we tested it along with other scripts (my native is Hebrew, also problematic) in a C# app three years ago.

Comment: This is most promising and very helpful. I don't need to encode for Hebrew, but I am familiar with the language..תודה רבה לך על העזרה שלך!